# How to make ajax get call for text to Java controller in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

I am expecting a BigDecimal.toString() value from Web call.

But i am not manage to configure it and getting either 404-Not found or 406.

Following is Spring MVC Code

```
 @RequestMapping(value="get/myData", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
 @ResponseBody
 public String getMyData(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, 
      @ModelAttribute("detailForm") DetailForm form)
 {
  //A web service called return big decimal and return that big decimal value toString
   return "Value";
 }
```

Following is calling code:

```
  var convId = $("#" + $("body form:first").attr("id")).find('input[name="_CONV_ID"]').val();



 blockUI: false,
            dataType: 'text',
            type: 'GET',
            url: "get/myData.do",
            data: { '_CONV_ID': convId},
            success: function (data) {
                // new dialog
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert("Error" + result);
            }
```

Could anyone please help me in adjusting code. On button click, a value is getting return from web service which is of BigDecimal type

Comment: your url in your ajax request seems false to me. Try : `get/myData.do` -> `get/myData`

Comment: No. That is not issue

Comment: do you submit a form at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Trying reaching the url `http://localhost:8080/your_application_name/get/myData`. If you find 404 error there, you need to check your web.xml. Check the section of servlet-mapping part.